# Openfire Server sending empty packets

Tags: ios, sockets, xmpp, openfire

I am using Openfire server to implement XMPP communication between multiple clients, but in iOS background mode we can not afford to read useless packets. Here as I observed from iOS logs & other client logs, Openfire server is sending some kind of empty packets to client every 2-3 seconds. I have verified this with Wireshark also.

Do anyone seen this before? how can I stop this behavior of Openfire server for sending empty packets?

Setup used for openfire:

- Openfire server version : 3.8.2
- TLS enabled
- Client ideal duration kept at 60 seconds, in Openfire server settings.

Comment: Empty TCP packets, or empty (message) stanzas? If former, then it could be whitespace pings, but those should't appear every 2-3 seconds.

Comment: NO STANZAS, It is whitespace ping , after analyzing more, it looks like it is sent after every 10 secs.

Comment: Got the issue, it was one jsp "session-summary" page of openfire server which on refresh, calls a method which in turn sends the whitespace ping to the clients. And I was using that page to check connectivity of my clients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the issue, it was one jsp "session-summary" page of openfire server which on refresh, calls a method which in turn sends the whitespace ping to the clients. And I was using that page to check connectivity of my clients.